# Mvc bundle request returns blank file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-bundling

The issue is the generated src url that mvc gives when it returns the page does not contain a version string.

So for the bundles that work we have: 
"url?v=Version String"

The bundles that don't work have a blank version string:
"url?v="

These bundles haven't changed since the last release and work in four seperate environments (files binary identical).

Anybody have any thoughts on environmental issues that could cause this?

All environments are azure websites.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does your RegisterBundles method look like? Is it being properly bootstrapped in the global.asax?

Comment: Yes. All our bundles are bootstrapped in the global.asax. Bare in mind this has worked in all other environments before live!

Comment: Where are the URLs coming from? Are you using the Styles.Render and Scripts.Render helper and they are outputting the blank URLs?

Comment: Yeah we're using the helpers you mention. They output the correct url without the version querystring.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem; I was misspelling the files to bundle: the bundler returned blank as there was nothing to return ad also couldn't calculate a version for the bundle. Never got the same error since i checked the paths every time